# Recurring payments

Tags: 7, ubercart, commerce

Looking for feedback from those who have experience or have done research on recurring payment options for Drupal 7. 
I'm familier with Ubercart UC Recurring for Drupal 6, but have not looked at Ubercart for D7.

My hope, since I'm rebuilding the site from the ground up in with D7, was to use Commerce. But so far, it doesn't appear that there is much support for recurring payments via the Commerce module.

Or... is there something besides Ubercart or Commerce that integrates well with Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want/need is an order (multiple products) to be recurring:

[Commerce Recurring](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring)

If what you want/need is a product (often times a service like hosting or a software license or a paid subscription) to be recurring:

[Commerce License Billing](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing) + [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license)

Regardless of those two options, you should definitely use the following module to deal with people who have credit cards that expire (everyone!):

[Commerce Dunning](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_dunning)

Comment: Looks like this requires storing credit card data on the site (at least for the license billing).  Any other options that don't require this?

Comment: Colan, this isn't so bad. You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile which has a number of payment gateways. It stores an anonymized token that the payment gateway will recognize as a saved credit card when used with your payment gateway credentials. Keeping the PCI Compliance requirements back at the Payment Gateway, where we want it.

Comment: Oh, that's fantastic.  Thanks!  I thought cardonfile required local storage of credit card data; happy to know I was wrong about that.